# vector magnitude for large components

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I noticed that numpy has a built in function linalg.norm(vector), which produces the magnitude. For small values I get the desired output

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.linalg.norm([0,2])
2.0
```

However for large values:

```
>>> np.linalg.norm([0,149600000000])
2063840737.6330884
```

This is a huge error, what could I do instead. Making my own function seems to produce the same error. What is the problem here, is a rounding error this big?, and what can I do instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your number is written as an integer, and yet it is too big to fit into a `numpy.int32`.  This problem seems to happen even in python3, where 
the native numbers are big.

In numerical work I try to make everything floating point unless it is an index.  So I tried:

```
In [3]: np.linalg.norm([0.0,149600000000.0])
Out[3]: 149600000000.0
```

To elaborate: in this case Adding the `.0` was an easy way of turning integers into doubles.  In more realistic code, you might have incoming data which is of uncertain type.  The safest (but not always the right) thing to do is just coerce to a floating point array at the top of your function.

```
def do_something_with_array(arr):
    arr = np.double(arr)   # or np.float32 if you prefer.
    ... do something ...
```